# Using a querystring parameter in an XSLT 2.0 SQL Query

Tags: aspdotnetstorefront

Here is the query that I am using. Let's assume that the URL which was used to access this page is `http://www.domain.com/default.aspx?id=3`

```
  <query name="SimpleQuery" rowElementName="Table" runif="showpage">
    <sql>
      <![CDATA[
        select * from Table where ID = @QueryStringID
      ]]>
    </sql>
    <queryparam paramname="@QueryStringID"       paramtype="request" requestparamname="id"        sqlDataType="int" defvalue="0"  validationpattern="" />
  </query>
```

So this should translate this query: `select * from Table where ID = 3`, but it is not getting the querystring parameter properly.

According to the AspDotNetStorefront documentation (http://manual.aspdotnetstorefront.com/p-157-xml-packages.aspx), the paramtype `request` can be used to access querystring variables, but I cannot figure out how.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

That looks right. Your query, however, might not be executing due to your runif attribute (runif="showpage").

Exert from the link you referenced:
"The runif attribute can be used to run the query under only certain circumstances. The value should be either a querystring/form/cookie param or an appconfig param. If the specified querystring/form/cookie param or an appconfig param doesn't exist or is an empty the query will not be executed. This could be used for a page where the query should not be run until the page is submitted with a form field."